# Post-clone hook in .hgrc is not always executed?

Tags: mercurial, hook, hgrc

I have created a post-clone hook in .hg/hgrc. This hook sometimes executed, and sometimes not, depending on which directory hg is called from.

Let the repository be in /path/to/repos/. The post-clone hook is in /path/to/repos/.hg/hgrc.

Cloning from /path/to/repos/, the post-clone hook is executed:

```
$ pwd
/path/to/repos/
$ hg clone ./ /path/to/myclone/
```

Cloning from /path/to, the post-clone hook is *not* executed:

```
$ pwd
/path/to/
$ hg clone repos myclone
```

Why is the hgrc in my repository not read/post-clone hook not executed in the latter case?

Regards,
Freddy

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to put the hook in your ~/hgrc file, rather than your repo's hgrc.

[Hooks do not propagate](https://book.mercurial-scm.org/read/hook.html)

i.e.. if you add hook to a repo, then clone the repo, don't expect the hook to be in the new clone.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the main text linked-to from [Tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63351450/3195477), in case [that page](https://book.mercurial-scm.org/read/hook.html) eventually changes or goes away:

> Hooks do not propagate
>
> ---
>
> In Mercurial, hooks are not revision controlled, and do not propagate
> when you clone, or pull from, a repository. The reason for this is
> simple: a hook is a completely arbitrary piece of executable code. It
> runs under your user identity, with your privilege level, on your
> machine.
>
> It would be extremely reckless for any distributed revision control
> system to implement revision-controlled hooks, as this would offer an
> easily exploitable way to subvert the accounts of users of the
> revision control system.
>
> Since Mercurial does not propagate hooks, if you are collaborating
> with other people on a common project, you should not assume that they
> are using the same Mercurial hooks as you are, or that theirs are
> correctly configured. You should document the hooks you expect people
> to use.
>
> In a corporate intranet, this is somewhat easier to control, as you
> can for example provide a “standard” installation of Mercurial on an
> NFS filesystem, and use a site-wide ~/.hgrc file to define hooks that
> all users will see. However, this too has its limits...

That last warning may have been referring to the very next section which adds:

> If you deploy a system- or site-wide ~/.hgrc file that defines some
> hooks, you should thus understand that your users can disable or
> override those hooks.